# Alert Won't Present in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, alert

Here is the code I am using:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingAlert: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Alert") {
                showingAlert = true
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"),
                  message: Text("Wear sunscreen"),
                  dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
    }
}
```

I tried tapping the Show Alert button so many times in the iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd Generation) simulator but nothing happens. What's wrong in the code above? or is it a bug in the latest simulator? (I am using Xcode 12.5).

Comment: it’s working fine for me. Tested on IOS 14.5, iPad Pro (11-inch) 3rd generation and Xcode 12.5.

Comment: This is really weird. Another friend has it running too on the same settings. May be my Xcode version is corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I have an alert in the parent view. It seems it blocked the one in the child view. Once I removed the alert from the parent one, the child's alert appeared. Thanks, swiftUI, for being so smart.